# Random calls incoming

Tags: redmi, virus

I am using Redmi note 7 (android: 9 PKQ1)
 I have run virus scans on my phone, but I am still having this problem: I keep getting random phone calls on my phone, but strangely there's nothing showing on screen. Only ringtone goes off and that's all. Even when I restart device nothing shows up in history catalog.
I'am pretty sure this is some kind of virus and I would like to know if anyone has got same problem as me and some advice on how to fix it.
Any suggestion for virus scanner better than common ones?

Regards,
Highzivs

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to check what apps have you installed by going into Settings. Find out which apps you cannot recognise but seem suspicious.

And the last resort – remove your so-called virus scanner as some of them are simply virus and luring you to install it to “prevent virus”.